# Finding equation of a circle

Tags: plane-geometry

I am supposed to find an equation of a circle passing though points M(3,0,0),N(0,3,0) and P(0,0,3) I have tried to find an intersection of bisectors of lines MN and NP but ended up with nothing.

Comment: So a circle in 3-dimensions?

Comment: A curve in$\mathbf R^3$ requires at least $2$ equations.

Comment: Hint:  By symmetry, the center is of the form $\{\lambda,\lambda,\lambda\}$.  The three points (hence the circle)  live in the plane $x+y+z=3$, so you can read the center off.

Answer (score 2):

It's not as hard as you may believe, in fact, you would use the following equation:

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2$$

Just an altered version of the circle equation where $C(a,b,c)$ is the center of our circle.

So all you do is plug in you numbers to get 3 equations:

$$(3-a)^2+b^2+c^2=r^2\tag{1}$$

$$a^2+(3-b)^2+c^2=r^2\tag{2}$$

$$a^2+b^2+(3-c)^2=r^2\tag{3}$$

Subtract $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get:

$$(3-a)^2-a^2+b^2-(3-b)^2=0$$

$$9-6a-9+6b=0$$

$$6b=6a\to a=b$$

Subtract $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$(3-b)^2-b^2+c^2-(3-c)^2=0$$

Following from above steps, we get:

$$a=b=c$$

From this, I want to assume that $a=b=c=0$ because I think it is obvious with the three points you chose and I want to have $r=3$, such that we have:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=3^2=9$$

Plugging in your points say that this works and we have the following:

$$3=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\pm\sqrt{x^2+(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})^2}$$

Basically, this is applying Pythagorean Theorem twice so that the points $x_1,y_1,z_1$ are all equidistant to the origin.

Since ask specifically for the circle, here you go:

$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2=6$$

Just remember to use the following equation:  $x+y+z=3$ to maintain the fact that it is a circle.

Comment: I tohught that equation above is an equation of a sphere,tha'ts why I was confused

Comment: Oh, you ask that?  A circle can only exist between three points that are coplanar because a circle is 2-dimensional.  If you did find the equation though, it would still be a sphere.

Comment: @user307370 consider the the sphere equation where $z=0$.  This produces the circle equation.

Answer (score 2):

Such a circle is the intersection of the sphere centred at origin that passes through $M,N,P$ and the plane through these points. Hence it is defined by the equations
$$\begin{cases}
x+y+z=3,\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=9.
\end{cases}$$
The centre of the circle is the projection of the origin onto the plane, i.e. the point $\Omega(1,1,1)$.

Comment: You sure it goes along the lines $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$?  Doesn't the center of the sphere have any effect?

Comment: There are other spheres that will intersect the plane in the circle circumscribed to  triangle $MNP$, i.e. the system of equations that define the circle is not unique. The system of equations I propose is the simplest, and anyway, the centres of the spheres are all on  the line $O\Omega$.